# Node Js - Angular Coss Origin Policy Error on - POST/GET/PUT - Methods

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, cross-browser, cross-domain

I created a website with a backend in node js,but at the moment someone is also in charge of developing an angular application.
For example the node structure from the creation of posts.

**Route structure**

**-app.js**

```
const postRoutes = require('./routes/postRoutes');
```

**-controller/postController.js**

```
exposts.createPosts = async(req,res)=>{
  const create = await Post.create(req.body);
           res.status(201).json({
           status:"success",
           data:create
            
       });
  }
```

**-routes/postRoutes.js**

```
router.route('/create-post').post(postController.createPosts);
```

This is how I create new posts and insert data into the database using a mongoose structure.

To insert the data from the UI into the database I use axios.

**-public/js/main.js**

```
import {createPostFnc} from './createPost';
  const create_posts= document.querySelector('#form');
       if(create_posts){
           create_posts.addEventListener('submit',(createPos)=>{
              createPos.preventDefault();
    
        const postData = new FormData();
           postData.append('title',document.getElementById('input1').value);
           postData.append('link',document.getElementById('input2').value);
           postData.append('description',document.getElementById('input3').value);
        
    

         createPostFnc(postData );
     });
 }
```

**-public/js/createPost.js**

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { showAlert } from './alert';
import { showAlertPost } from './alert-post'; 

 export const createPostFnc  = async(dataPost) =>{
    try{
       const post = await axios({
          method:"POST",
          url:"{url}/api/v3/posts/create-post",
          data:dataPost
       });
       if(post.data.status === 'success'){
           showAlertPost('post-success','Processing');
           window.setTimeout(()=>{
               location.assign('/persona-profile');
           }, 1500);
        }
      }catch(err){
        showAlert('error','There was a problem creating yout post!!!');
         console.log(err);
    }    
}
```

So far so good!!!
But in the angular when trying the same thing to create a post after url,
receives this error.
[image]

I had the same error with the account creation and login routes,
I solved this error by adding in **app.js**.

```
//Allow Cross Origin Platform
app.use(function(req ,res ,next){
   res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*");
   res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,POST,PUT");
   res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers","Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, 
    Authorization");
   next();
});
```

But for the post routes it doesn't work, after I tried to solve the problem using the [cors module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors)

I tried something like that.
**-routes/postRoutes.js**

```
const cors = require('cors')

router.route('/create-post').post(cors(),postController.createPosts);
```

As a simple way to solve the problem but it doesn't work.
How can I resolve this error so that it can allow the interaction between the application and the server.

**Notice:I am new to node js under one year experience.**

Answer (score 0):

Set the Headers correctly

```js
// Add headers
app.use(function (req, res, next) {

    // Website you wish to allow to connect
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');

    // Request methods you wish to allow
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');

    // Request headers you wish to allow
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');

    // Set to true if you need the website to include cookies in the requests sent
    // to the API (e.g. in case you use sessions)
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);

    // Pass to next layer of middleware
    next();
});
```

Comment: I will build today the delete route ,but to post method it give error 503.